# How to use different image on mobile in ReactJs Slick

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, slick.js

Is there any way to use mobile image different from the desktop mode in react slick slider? I can use display none for breakpoints but what I want to learn, Is there any different way to do it?

```
const Hero = () => {
  const classes = useStyle();
  const { push } = useRouter();
  const [sliderState, setSliderState] = useState(heroSliderData);
  const [my_swiper, set_my_swiper] = useState({});
  return (
    <section className={classes.section}>
        <Grid style={{ width:"100%", padding: "0px" }}>
        <Swiper
              loop={true}
              navigation={true}
              onInit={(ev) => {
                set_my_swiper(ev);
              }}
            >
              {sliderState.map(({ id, mainheading, mainheading2, subheading, subheading2, buttontext, image }) => (
              <SwiperSlide key={id}>
                <Grid item className={classes.hero}>
                <img className={classes.heroimg} src={image} style={{ position:"relative"}} />
          <Grid item xs={12} style={{ position:"absolute", top:"30%", left:"0", right:"0", textAlign: "center" }}>
            <Typography variant="h1" className={classes.h1}>
            {mainheading}<br />
            {mainheading2}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} style={{ position:"absolute", top:"42%", left:"0", right:"0", textAlign: "center" }}>
            <Typography variant="h2" className={classes.h2}>
            {subheading} 
              <br/>
              {subheading2}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} style={{ position:"absolute", top:"52%", left:"0", right:"0", textAlign: "center" }}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              onClick={() => push("/teklif-al")}
              className={classes.teklifal}
            >
              {buttontext}
            </Button>
          </Grid>
          </Grid>
          </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
          </Swiper>
        </Grid>
    </section>
  );
};
```

This is my code that I am working on it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an IF clause to show and hide images?

See docs of [React Slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/multiple-items).

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

export default class MultipleItems extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> Multiple items </h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>7</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>8</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>9</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And modify like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

export default class MultipleItems extends Component {
  const showOnMobile = document.innerWidth < 769;
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> Multiple items </h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>
         {showOnMobile &&
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          }
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>7</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>8</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>9</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Mario thanks for your fast reply, I am so new on this, sorry for not understanding.

I'am attaching codes to my question. How can I use IF clause in this structure.

Comment: @newbiemrt, thanks for adding code, I still do not fully understand what you want. You want to show different images on mobile? If so, just use a condition.

Comment: yes @mario , I want to show desktop slider and mobile sliders differently.